# Git checkout for Angular application showing different

Tags: git, gitlab

- I am trying to check out this branch name sports(2) but I am getting below error
  bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
- but when I check out branch name sports without brackets I am not getting an error.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my git comment below.

  $ git checkout sports(2)

  bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: This is a shell quoting issue - try `git checkout "sports(2)"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use quotes "sports(2)"

And I would recommend to not use parenthesis or any brackets in names.